# If statement in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I can't figure out the syntax to use an if clause in a LINQ to SQL statement.

The statement works by getting the unique values from a column called `Staff_No`

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => 
item.Staff_No).Distinct().ToList();
```

I am trying to get the unique values from `Staff_No` when the data equals as string from a column called `Section`.
I know this is wrong, but I hope you can get the jist of what I have been trying to do in C#?

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Select(item => 
if item.Section == "Level 1" then item.Staff_No).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Use Where: sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(item => 
item.Section == "Level 1").Select(item => item.Staff_No).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer everyone. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs
   .Where(item => item.Section == "Level 1")
   .Select(item => item.Staff_No)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Up vote for taking the time. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Visual Studio right now, but I think you an do that using a Where statement :

```
var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(item => item.Section == "Level 1").Select(item => item.Staff_No).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Up vote for taking the time. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You try `Where`

```
    var staffNames = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs
                     .Where(wr=>wr.Section == "Level 1")
                     .Select(item => item.Staff_No)
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Up vote  for taking the time. All of the answers worked for me.